# Understanding proj4, epsg and esri *.prj in depth?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, references, epsg, prj

Where can I find a good resource that teaches me

1) about the difference between proj4, EPSG and ESRI *.prj? (Why do several coordinate system definitions exist? When should I use which? How are they defined?)

2) how the conversion between these systems works in detail.

I came across these questions while encountering a problem with EPSG 2056 which I defined using the proj4 string (I wrongly assumed that the EPSG is an ID for the proj4 string). When exporting this coordinate system to a shapefile using the function st_write from the R package sf I realized that the ESRI *.prj file did not translate correctly. I assume it has something to do with the towgs84 paramter which ESRI does not recognize.

Comment: If you have an EPSG authority code then you should use the [EPSG registry](http://epsg-registry.org/) to discover what it's properties are. That is the definitive reference. Similarly an ESRI:code is defined by ESRI.  To be aware, though that sometimes codes are specified as being defined by EPSG, when they are not, for example you might see `EPSG:102100` the code 102100 is not defined by the EPSG authority it's a code use by ESRI and should be referenced as `ESRI:102100`

Comment: You can learn a bit more by looking at the wiki for the epsg tag on this question